# Simplifying $e^{-i x\log n}+e^{i x\log n}(2^{{1 \over 2}+ i x}\pi^{-{1 \over 2}+i x}\cos({\pi\over 4}-{{\pi i x}\over 2})\Gamma({1\over 2}-i x))$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

I'm working with an equation that has the following term in it:

$$e^{-i x\log n}+e^{i x\log n}(2^{{1 \over 2}+ i x}\pi^{-{1 \over 2}+i x}\cos({\pi\over 4}-{{\pi i x}\over 2})\Gamma({1\over 2}-i x))$$

The two exponentials outside the parathesis are reminiscent of the well-known cosine identity, $\cos(x) = {1 \over 2}({{e^{-i x}+e^{i x}}) }$, of course.  And graphing the equation, it does superficially look some wave with a frequency matching $\cos(x \log n)$ makes up a part of my equation.

Is there some way to simplify or rewrite this equation that makes that clearer?

Comment: What do we know about $x,n$?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  n is a positive whole number.  x is a complex number, although the special case of x being a real number would also be interesting to me.